# Importing DEM to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem

I downloaded a DEM file (package, rather?) of the entire US from usgs.gov. It's 30GB and contains quite a few files.

Is it possible to import this to QGIS to overlay the data on my map?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Esri grid (also known as an Arc/INFO binary grid) format raster.  The Esri grid (and other ancient Arc/INFO formats such as the coverage vector format) is a directory of related files stored in a parent directory (workspace) with an INFO database directory.

[image]

Qgis can read ESRI grids, just unzip and add the `aspect/hdr.adf` file.

Note: It looks like (just based on the name) that you downloaded an aspect raster, not a DEM. Aspect is [derived from a DEM](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-aspect-works.htm) but doesn't contain any elevation values and you can't reverse the aspect calculation to derive elevation.